# redirect to original URL without query string using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a url with any query string to its original url.

Something like:

```
mysite.com/?any=query -> mysite.com/
mysite.com/page/?any=query&more=query -> mysite.com/page/
```

I'm already using this rules to redirect any file to `index.php` on root directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule !^index\.php %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help...but it worked only for root url: `mysite.com/?any=query -> mysite.com/` **WORKS** ...but when i have one or more subdirs after root url it isnt working: `mysite.com/page/?any=query -> mysite.com/page/?any=query` **NOT WORKING**